# Do I need to care about socket's lifetime in call to async_write?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm calling asio::async_write this way:

```
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using std::string;

shared_pointer<tcp::socket> tcp_socket_pointer;
string message;

...

void send() {
    asio::async_write(
        *tcp_socket_pointer,
        asio::buffer(message),
        boost::bind(
            &handle_send, // defined elsewhere
            asio::placeholders::error,
            asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
    );
}
```

Now, in my code it is possible that between calls to `send` and `handle_send` the socket I pass gets destroyed because `tcp_socket_pointer` goes out of it's scope.

Is it legal? I mean, do I need to ensure that the referenced tcp::socket persists until the asynchronous operation completes? 
My intuition tells me that asio::async_write makes a system call immediately so I wouldn't need to worry, but I better ask :).

In case it doesn't work as I'm expecting, is it a good idea to pass `tcp_socket_pointer` as an argument to `handle_send` in order to make sure that tcp::socket it points to doesn't expire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this, but the `async_*` call will be canceled when the `tcp::socket` is destroyed.

You may want to keep a shared_ptr to the socket and bind it to the completion handler so it keeps a reference, which is indeed what you describe.

Comment: It will cancel, but not throw runtime error? That would be exactly the behaviour I wish to have :)). BTW, how can boost check whether the socket got destroyed having an ordinary reference?

Comment: @kitek It can't. When you call the destructor on the object, it does a cancel on the same object. If you want to find out whether a socket is destroyed without holding a (shared) reference, use `boost::weak_ptr` (or `std::weak_ptr`)

Comment: That's what is bothering me, because `async_write` is a generic function that works in while loop till it writes all. Therefore, I worry there's a possibility that this code breaks.

Comment: @kitek `async_write` does not use a `while` loop, it always returns immediately.

Comment: @Sam I was assuming he meant _he's_ using it as an Actor-based loop (chaining more `async_writes` from the completion handler). Anyways, yes, by all means manage lifetime. _Don't ride your city bike off-road in the mountains_. Stuff like that.